# java iterator error sorting through hashset

Tags: java, iteration, hashset

I need to return the values that contain both the negative and postive value using a HashSet, while maintaining order. This is what I have but I keep getting an error. Any help would be awesome.

```
public static double[] negated(double[] a)
{
    Set<Double> x = new HashSet<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        x.add((Double)a[i]);
    }


    for(double e : x)
    {
       if (x.contains(-e) == false)
       {
          x.remove(e);
       }
    }

    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(x);
    double[] b = new double[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (list.contains(a[i]))
        {
          b[i] = list.get(i);
        }
    }

    return b;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] c = {3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -5, -3, 9};
    System.out.println(negated(c));
        }
```

This is the error:

```
xception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
at Ass10.negated(Ass10.java:144)
at Ass10.main(Ass10.java:182)
```

Comment: can you let us know, what is the error?

Comment: @mohammadshamsi my bad. it has been edited.

Comment: Did you import `Set`, `List` and all of the other things you use? This looks like a simple compile error that something like Eclipse or Netbeans could fix in a jiffy...

Comment: @tjameson Imported the packages, and I tried NetBeans on my other rig, and I'm not having anymore luck.

Comment: Also, you don't need the line `Iterator itr = x.iterator();`. When you post questions on StackOverflow you should attempt to make your code as concise as possible before posting :)

Comment: You are not using `itr` - just delete the line and move on

Comment: @Jeff Nice catch that was something I was working on earlier. Deleted that line and I;m now getting a different error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the list as you're iterating over it. This is illegal:

```
for(double e : x) {
    if (x.contains(-e) == false) {
        x.remove(e);
    }
}
```

The better way to do it is to make a new `Set<double>` with the things you want to keep:

```
Set<Double> list = new HashSet<Double>();
for (double e : x) {
    if (x.contains(-e)) {
        list.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you know that the number of items you're removing is likely to be very small then you could make a list of items to *remove*, and then remove them *en masse* at the end of the iteration.